# Animate 3D group Scatter plot with respect to time MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, user-interface, plot, matlab-figure

Hello and thank you in advance for your help!
I made a 3D scatter plot with 4 color groups using MATLAB (uploaded, see below ).
Now I want to animate the scatter plot with respect to time. So if each point has a time stamp I would like to show them in order.

So for example: if I have points A, B, C that repent errors on a specific xyz location of a car, and error A was made at 10AM and error B at 12PM and error C at 3PM I want to plot the points in that order in an animation.

Also if possible I would like to make a GUI with a scrolling bar so I can scroll trough time or back in time and thus adding points as I go forward into time or removing points as I go back in time. or at least an option to pause the scater process.

Note: the scatter plot is going to have about 2000-3000 points … I don’t know if this will make a difference. Im also  new to MATLAB :-)

Thank you very much for your help and time!
Kind regards

Alfredo

---

```
%Scatterplot data

x = [ 50 55 200 210 350 360 400 450 550 560 600 670 750 850 860];
y = [ 50 -50 100 -100 150 -150 151 -151 150 -150 152 -152 150 -150 150];
z = [ 120 120 100 300 100 300 100 300 100 300 100 300 100 300 100];

% alocates space for the z data by creating a matrix array of all ones
g = [0*ones(3,1);1*ones(3,1); 2*ones(3,1); 3*ones(3,1); 4*ones(3,1); ];

%set specific RGB color value for positions 0-4 and background color
color = [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 0; 0 1 0]

whitebg([  0.6758    0.8438    0.8984]) % light blue background


% gscatter creates a 2D matrix with the values from x and y
% and creates groups acording to the 'g' matrix size
% h = gscatter captures output argument and returns an array of handles to the lines on the graph)
h = gscatter(x, y, g, color)

%% for each unique group in 'g', set the ZData property appropriately
gu = unique(g);
for k = 1:numel(gu)
set(h(k), 'ZData', z( g == gu(k) ));
end

%set the aspect ratio, grid lines, and Legend names for the 3D figure 
daspect([4.5 5 5])
grid on
legend('Position 0','Position 1','Position 2','Position 3','Position 4')

% view a 3D grapgh (for 2D set to "2")
view(3)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please note that it is commonly appreciated here that you ask only one question per post, and keep questions short and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to show all the different scatter plots after one another. That is easy enough; just append this to the code you have:

```
% loop through time
xl = xlim;
yl = ylim;
zl = zlim;
for ii = h(:).'
    % switch all scatter plots off
    set(h, 'visible', 'off')
    % switch only 1 on, for the current time
    set(ii, 'visible', 'on');

    % set original limits
    xlim(xl); ylim(yl); zlim(zl);

    % draw and some delay
    drawnow, pause(1);
end
```

As for the slider, here's an example of how to do that. Append this to the code you have:

```
xl = xlim;
yl = ylim;
zl = zlim;

slider = uicontrol(...
    'parent', gcf,...
    'style', 'slider',...
    'min', 0,...
    'max', 4,...
    'sliderstep', [1/4 1/4],...
    'units', 'normalized',...
    'position', [0.05 0.05 0.90 0.05],...    
    'callback', @SliderCallback);

function SliderCallback(sliderObj, ~)
    set(h, 'visible', 'off')
    set(h(get(sliderObj, 'Value')+1), 'visible', 'on')
    xlim(xl); ylim(yl); zlim(zl);
end
```

Note that this uses a nested `function`, which implies your entire script needs to become a function (which is really the proper way to do things of any appreciable size anyway).